# Why don't react use red-black tree to shape its model?

Tags: reactjs

Red-black tree is a kind of AVL tree which is widely used in data base for it is efficient in CRUD. Why react do not use it as its virtual DOM tree model? You'd better give me a mathematic proof.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a reason that AVL tree is to make searching more quickly, but in UI area, we often concentrate on tree's diff and transform. But another question, is there a kind of data structure can make tree diff and transform more efficient?